# TFS Build Agent Can't Connect to Package Feed

Tags: tfs, nuget, azure-devops, authorization, tfsbuild

A little info on our setup:

- On-Prem TFS 2018 Update 2 (running as domain Service Account A)
- Separate Win2k16 VM hosting a build agent (using a domain Service Account B to run the agent)
- Package feed hosted inside a collection on TFS

So this has worked for a few months now (the new piece being the package feed for our own-developed NuGet packages). On an MVC project utilizing our build servers, the NuGet Restore task fails when trying to connect to our package feed. On fail, the message is:

```
http://TFS_URL:8080/tfs/Development/_packaging/CustomNuGetFeed/nuget/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source http://TFS_URL:8080/tfs/Development/_packaging/CustomNuGetFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

That's all the info that the build log spits out; I dove deeper and spun up WireShark and got the following:

**Request**

```
GET /tfs/Development/_packaging/CustomNuGetFeed/nuget/v3/index.json HTTP/1.1
user-agent: NuGet Command Line/4.4.1 (Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)
X-NuGet-Client-Version: 4.4.1
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Authorization: Basic <base64_token>
Host: tfs:8080
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-TFS-ProcessId: d9a45aba-cc82-4f2c-98a3-e4441bfa456f
ActivityId: e780f2d6-1216-46ac-8c66-cb89379c7811
X-TFS-Session: e780f2d6-1216-46ac-8c66-cb89379c7811
X-VSS-E2EID: e780f2d6-1216-46ac-8c66-cb89379c7811
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="tfs"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"
Lfs-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Tue, 16 Oct 2018 19:57:17 GMT
Content-Length: 1293
```

**Response page message**

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

However, there's a .NET Core app that still restores packages fine as far as I can tell (unless it's only retrieving the packages from cache).

The credentials for  the service account have not changed at all.  I've made sure the service accounts have access to the feed, according to these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=vsts&tabs=previous-nav

I've also tried disabling Basic Auth in IIS for the TFS site on the TFS server, and enabling Windows auth.  Neither of which worked either.

So I'm at a loss at what the issue could be from all that I've tried/looked into.

Comment: Based on the error message `401 - Unauthorized`, it should be an permission issue, so you need to double check the permission settings...

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT The permissions "seem" to be correct in some fashion, as I can remote into the VM with the Build Agent as the Service Account, open a browser, and navigate to the Package Feed without an error.  However, trying to run "nuget restore" on the VM itself, also errors out (it only says "cannot find package of version").  Restoring through Visual Studio works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after upgrading to Azure DevOps Server 2019.0.1, I was still receiving a 401 Unauthorized when attempting to authenticate to a package feed that was hosted in the same collection.

**Workaround**

The work around I had used was to place the package binaries inside the build server's package cache folder, located here:
C:\Users\.nuget\packages

**Working Solution**

However a solution has been found with the help of Microsoft's VS Community.  An updated cred provider needs to be used with the NuGet Restore task.

Nuget 4.8+ needs to be used for this to work, and then 2 build variables need to be added to the build definition: 
NuGet_ForceEnableCredentialProviderV2 = true 
NuGet.ForceEnableCredentialProvider = false

According to a Microsoft rep, this will be enabled by default on ADOS 2019.1 update.

You can view the full thread here: 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/360323/tfs-build-agent-cant-connect-to-package-feed.html

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; nuget was too old. Updating it helped.

We had the same problem after setting up a new build agent machine for a TFS 2018 on Windows 2019. However, we did not use wireshark to inspect traffic, so this might be unrelated. Same symptoms though: one solution worked (using paket), the *other* didn't work (using nuget).

The issue was that the *other* solution used a nuget (version 2.x) from a committed thirdparty directory. Nuget is designed to use a 'global' nuget from %localappdata%\nuget if available. And that global nuget version didn't exist. Updating nuget as the build agent user fixed the issue, and placed a recent nuget version into %localappdata%:

```
nuget.exe update -self
```

I think that the TFS 2018 requires NTLM authentication instead of basic authentication (which still seemed to be supported  by TFS 2017). It still strikes me as weird that the installed VS 2017.9.5 didn't update nuget.

Comment: Is the "global" nuget version the one inside the "agent\externals\nuget" directory?

Comment: Good question, showed me I was slightly wrong. The "global" nuget didn't exist for me, but the version in the 3rdparty folder was old (2.8.x). 'nuget.exe update -self' actually fetched the current version (4.9.x) from nuget.org and placed it into the %localappdata%\nuget folder.